# should rate of change be negative

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Say I have a spherical snowball. I want it's average rate of change of surface area as radius goes from 25cm to 20cm. I did the calculation.

$f(r)=4*\pi*r^2$.

That's the formula of surface area of sphere

So I did $\dfrac{f(25)-f(20)}{25-20}$

Which gave me a positive number but I am confuse. Snowballs are melting so should not their rates of change be negative?

Comment: I am glad that you are actually caring about your result! Many see the output and treat it as a meaningless number.

Yes it is common to get the wrong sign in a problem, usually if you exchange the two components you will see the correct output. Later on you might find this occurring in integration(not sure of your current level).

Answer (score 1):

The average rate of change you're thinking of is $$\frac{\text{new }f-\text{old }f}{|\text{new }r - \text{old }r|}$$
which is the negative of what you've calculated. The ordering is important. You've calculated the average rate of change going from $r=20$ to $r=25$, which I'm sure you would agree should be positive and then makes sense.

Regarding the modulus: Without it, we're calculating the gradient of the line segment connecting the two points. The ordering then doesn't matter. This result would be positive (just consider the graph).

Comment: I would still get a negative over a negative, giving me a positive number, no?

Comment: @kirish He meant to exchange only the top. The bottom is change in time/size/etc, this is a magnitude. I am assuming you are referring to average change in. If you are referring to average rate of change, it is always positive. Since it is a rate of change.

Comment: oops. quick fix to that.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the average rate of change. We are always positive. When looking at the average change in the quantities. We will look at:

$$\frac{ \text{ new } f - \text { old } f}{\text{ magnitude of change in time/size/etc }}$$

However, we will always refer to $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ when finding average rate of change, this is a positive quantity, since we are referring to how much it has changed, not how it has changed.